# Linear Regression Curve in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to implement the linear Regression curve mentioned at this link in R and need help.

Link: [Linear Regression Curve](http://www.onlinetradingconcepts.com/TechnicalAnalysis/LinRegCurve.html)

I found the following ThinkScript code that implements what I am looking for. Any help in converting it to R?

```
script inertiaTS {
    input y = close;
    input n = 20;
    rec x = x[1] + 1;
    def a = (n * Sum(x * y, n) - Sum(x, n) * Sum(y, n) ) / ( n * Sum(Sqr(x), n) - Sqr(Sum(x, n)));
    def b = (Sum(Sqr(x), n) * Sum(y, n) - Sum(x, n) * Sum(x * y, n) ) / ( n * Sum(Sqr(x), n) - Sqr(Sum(x, n)));
    plot InertiaTS = a * x + b;
}
```

Here is what I have so far..

```
Sqr <- function(x) {
return (x^2)
}

inertiaTS <- function(y, n) {
    x <- x + 1;
    a <- (n * rollapply( x*y, n, sum) - rollapply( x, n, sum ) * rollapply( y, n, sum )) / ( n * rollapply( Sqr(x), n, sum ) - Sqr(rollapply( x, n, sum )))
    b <- (rollapply( Sqr(x), n, sum) * rollapply( y, n, sum ) - rollapply( x, n, sum ) * rollapply( x*y, n, sum ) ) / ( n * rollapply( Sqr(x), n, sum ) - Sqr

(rollapply( x, n, sum )))
    return (a * x + b)
}
```

When I make a call to the function with

lrc <- inertiaTS(Cl(stockData$AAPL), 20)

I get the following error. Any help with this?

Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument

Thanks.

Comment: What is x and where is it defined?  x appears to be used in inertiaTS before Sqr is called.  Is the equation for b cutoff?  Consider providing a reproducible example with a small data set. Is rollapply from the zoo package?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do. See the link Below for explanation.

[Linear Regression Moving Average](http://research.scottrade.com/public/knowledgecenter/education/article.asp?docId=746bb09e49b74c0fb5251ec25d088c55) 

Given a Price Data series and the length, I would like to calculate the Linear Regression Lines and connect all the mid points of the lines so that it forms a moving average. This Linear Regression Moving Average reduces tha lag.

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions or respond to any of my suggestions.  Looking at the post again, I suspect `(rollapply( x, n, sum )))` is supposed to be a continuation of `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rollapply` and `lm` do the task:

```
library(zoo)
inertiaTS <- function(y, n) {
  x <- 1:n;
  c.ab=rollapply(y,n,function(yt){
    coef(lm(yt~x))
  },align = "right")                                                                                                                    
  plot(y,col=2)
  lines(c.ab[ ,2]*x[n]+c.ab[ ,1],col=4,lwd=2)
  list(axpb=c.ab[ ,2]*x[n]+c.ab[ ,1],rolcoef=c.ab)
}

#simulate any ts series
set.seed(123)
y=ts(10+sort(rnorm(150,sd=.8))+runif(150))
plot(y)
res<-inertiaTS(y,20)
```

[image]
    tail(res$axpb)

```
[1] 11.84216 11.95979 12.06342 12.05539 12.06578 12.19312
```